# Can not Set shop URL, nothing under Shop URL in configuration summary in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop

I'm using Prestashop 1.6.1.22. When trying to Set shop URL in "URL & SEO" there is only empty space below "Set SHOP URL". When checking sites configuration it shows:

> PrestaShop version 1.6.1.22
>
> Shop URL
>
> Currently used template

As you can see it shows nothing under shop URL.
BUT- when looking into database it shows my (correct) URL in Configuration table. (PS_SHOP_DOMAIN, PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the **ps_shop_url** table in your DB.

This is the table used to store shop URLs since Prestashop 1.5 due to multishop capabilities.

Values in **ps_configuration** are there only for retrocompatibility I guess.

Comment: There is ps_shop_url in my DB. domain, domain_ssl and physical_uri values are correct.

Comment: Those are the same values displayed in the "Traffic & SEO" backoffice page. Otherwise you are connected to a wrong database, I guess.

Comment: Database is correct, I've just double checked in "settings.inc.php".